# ReactJS: React-Router pass value to another page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have need to pass a value from a page to another using react-router.

I have tried in this way:

```
<li>
    <A 
      className="btn btn-link btn-sm"
      href={{ pathname: Routes.detail_page, search: `?_id=${C.Code}`, state: this.props.current  }}>
      { 'Open' }
    </A>
</li>
```

I would pass this.props.current to Detail Page.

In the other page if I tried in the componentDidMount() to print `this.props.current` it result undefined (of course in the first page this value is parametrized).

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    };
  }
componentDidMount(){
    let C = this.props.current
    console.log("C is: ", C) // this is undefined
    this.updateIsDeletableState()
  }
```

How can I do?

Comment: could you add your "the other page code"?

Comment: I only have tried to print the `this.props.current` usign console.log in the componentDidMount(). What do you need to know? :)

Comment: I want to see how did you code.

Comment: I have edited the message

Comment: Make sure you have the following in your component where you are trying to access the props:
```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
     //states
  };
}
```

Comment: @idhruv Yes I have it (I edit my code another time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure that you have defined URL parameter in the `Route`

```
// file-where-you-define-routes.js
...
<Switch>
  <Route path={`your-path/:id`} component={YourComponent} />
</Switch>
...
```

Then use hook `useParams` to get the parameter

```
function YourComponent() {
  const { id } = useParams();
  let C = id;
  console.log("C is: ", C) // this should be defined now
  ...
}
```

OR if you use class component `this.props.match.params.id`

```
class YourComponent extends Component {
  ...
  componentDidMount(){
    let C = this.props.match.params.id; // match
    console.log("C is: ", C) // this should be defined now
    this.updateIsDeletableState()
  }
}
```

Comment: Additionally, the route can declaration can also be updated as following to pass the props
`<Route exact path="/props-through-render" render={(props) => <PropsPage {...props} title={`Props through render`} />} />`