# I want to pass data to a page with <Link /> using react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Ok so in my item shop component I have a map to return a link for each element and when I click to go to that page with more description about that item for start I just want to make this work to a single page and here is my code from item shop component

```
render() {

        return (
            <>
                <div className="wrapper">
                    {this.context.dailyShop.map((item, idx) => (
                        <div key={idx} className="itemCard">
                            <div className="itemtest">
                                <p className="textName text">{item.item.name}</p>
                                <p className="textCost text">{item.store.cost}</p>
                                <Link to={{
                                    pathname: `/single`,
                                    state: [{ id: 1, name: 'Ford', color: 'red' }]
                                }}>
                                    <img className="itemPhoto" src={item.item.images.background} alt="alt" />
                                </Link>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </div>
            </>
        )
    }
```

and here is the code from that page named SingleItem

```
import React from 'react';
import Itemshop from '../data/Itemshop';

const Singleitem = ({ match }) => {



    return (
        <div>
            hello from single page item {match.params.name}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Singleitem
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62571061/reactjs-react-router-pass-value-to-another-page/62571233#62571233

Comment: what is the issue you are facing then ?

Comment: i cant get that data in single page

Comment: can you log the props and check ?

Answer (score 0):

```
hello from single page item {match.params.name}
```

I think, your statement should be in

```
props.location.state[0].name
```

not in match, because it will be saved it to location as query.

Code demo

```
const Demo= (props) => {
if (!!props.location.state) {
    console.log(props.location.state);
}
return (
<div>
  <Link
    to={{
      pathname: `/management/comic/1234/chapter`,
      state: [{ a: "abc", c: "awd" }],
    }}>
    link
  </Link>
  {!!props.location.state && props.location.state[0].a}
</div>
);};
export default Demo;
```

Comment: i am getting undefined

Comment: you should show log from [props.location.state], you will see data you sent, i check on my PC, and it works normally

Comment: yeah i console.log(props) and in location the state is undefined

Comment: maybe is a problem in itemshop

Comment: ow i chaged in itemshop ther link pathname to "/single/${item.name},

Comment: and i get the current state but i navigate to an undefined location and when i tri to get in state the item.name i am getting undefined again

Comment: i updated code demo for your problem, you can check it. because i dont' have your data, so i just mock data :D